# Chart.js change Color of a Point during runtime

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, chart.js

I am creating a diagram for the evaluation of a probe. So far everything works. Only I would like to change the color of individual data points during runtime. But I try it for a long time, have read various forum posts and but I fail.

I tried it like this. The message comes, the point jumps, but the color remains black.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Anzeige</title>
    <script src="dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFF00" vlink="#FFFF00">
  <style media="all" type="text/css">@import "CSS/anzeige.css";</style>



       <div id='zeile_1'>
         <div style="float: left; height:200px; width:5%; padding-left:1%" ><font size=2>MP</font><font size=5><br>1</font><br><br><font size=2>St.</font><font size=5><br>1</font></div>

      <div style="float: left; height:350px; width:94%">

         <canvas id='MP1'></canvas><button id='randomizeDataMP1'>Randomize Data</button>      <script>
          var   Chart1ctx = document.getElementById('MP1').getContext('2d');
var Chart1 = new Chart(Chart1ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create


    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {

          //labels:  ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
           labels: ['Pos 1' ,'Pos 2' ,'Pos 3' ,'Pos 4' ,'Pos 5' ,'Pos 6' ,'Pos 7' ,'Pos 8' ,'Pos 9' ,'Pos 10' ,'Pos 11' ,'Pos 12' ,'Pos 13' ,'Pos 14' ,'Pos 15' ,'Pos 16' ,],



        datasets: [{
           label: 'Tol Oben',
borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
fill: false,
 pointRadius:0,
 data: [1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,1.935 ,]
             },
             {
           label: 'Tol Unten',
borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
fill: false,
 pointRadius:0,
 data: [1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,1.905 ,]
             },
             {
           label: 'Tol Sollwert',
borderColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
fill: false,
 pointRadius:0,
 data: [1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,1.920 ,]
             },
             {
           label: 'Tol Oben',
pointBackgroundColor:  'rgba(0, 0, 0,1)',
 pointRadius:3,
showLine: false,
 data: [1.901 ,1.934 ,1.936 ,1.918 ,1.925 ,1.912 ,1.909 ,1.903 ,1.92 ,1.914 ,1.914 ,1.923 ,1.921 ,1.938 ,1.906 ,1.926 ,]
             },

             {
            label: 'Bar Dataset',
            data: [
            1.938, 1.938, 1.938, , , , , 1.938, , , , , , 1.938, 1.938, , ],
            backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)', 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)', , , , , 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)', , , , , , 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)', 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)', ,             ],
            type: 'bar'

             }
             ]

    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {
        scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               stepSize: 0.005
            }
          }]
        },
     responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
            display: false }
    }
});


 document.getElementById('randomizeDataMP1').addEventListener('click', function() {
     alert('Button Click');  

    Chart1.data.datasets[3].data[2] = 1.94;
    Chart1.config.data.datasets[3]['pointBackgroundColor'][2] = 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.5)';
    window.Chart1.update();


     });

      </script>
      </div>

  </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me? A small example script would certainly help me a lot to recognize my thinking error?

SPages

PS.: Sorry, English is not my native language but I try my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array for colors

[image]

```
Chart1.config.data.datasets[3]['pointBackgroundColor'] = Array.from(Array(16)).map((e, i) => i === 2 ? 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.5)' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)' );
```

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so simple when you know it. Thank you very much :) +1